# Handling errors in discord.py (no permission)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a moderation bot with commands like kick, ban, prune, etc, and I have all of the commands, but I can't figure out how to handle the error you get when the sender doesn't have permission. This is my code so far:

```
@commands.command(name='kick')
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'User {member.mention} has been kicked for: "{reason}".')

@kick.error
async def kick_error(self, error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, error.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(":redTick: You don't have permission to kick members.")
```

No error shows up in the console, but the message doesn't send.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that when a user with invalid permissions tries to use that command, the exception is caught in `error`, however, `error` is just the exception that is caught by `discord.py`since the user did not have permission. Therefore, the function is catching the error, no problem, but your if-statement is failing because because `error.MissingPermissions` is not an instance of error. It doesn't even exist since `error` is just what the exception thrown by discord.py that your function caught. There is no `MissingPermissions` as a part of that. Therefore, there is no such thing as `MissingPermissions` from the error you caught because that's just an error. You need to see if `error` is an instance of `MissingPermissions` from the `discord.py` missing permissions class (which it is). Thus, in order to fix it, import the `MissingPermissions` and you'll be good to go. I've fixed the code for you below.

```
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions

# Code

@kick.error
async def kick_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(":redTick: You don't have permission to kick members.")
```

Sorry if the explanation is unclear. I can try to explain it again if you'd like me to or someone can edit this to make it clearer and more accurate.

Comment: I edited the code. I realize that when working with any command in `discord.py` context must be first argument that is passed, then you can pass in any error or additional arguments you wish to pass. Try it now.

I also tested your code on my server. I did get an exception in the console with your code, so it is possible something else may be interfering with your code which is why you're not getting any kind of error. However, when I fixed it, it worked without any kind of exception being thrown in the console. So, try my edit and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

`commands.MissingPermissions` not `error.MissingPermissions`

Comment: Nope, that didn't do it.

Comment: add `raise(error)` at the end of the error handler and see whats the error that is raised

Comment: Nothing showed up in the console. I even tried removing the handler completely and there's no error anymore?

Answer (score 0):

also if you faced an exception: `ctx is a required attribute that is missing`

it is because your bot isn't in a class.
The solution:

```
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions

# Code

@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(":redTick: You don't have permission to kick members.")
```

in short, remove the self attribute. This answer may seem silly, but to only experts.
i expect beginners will find this as helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You are missing permission(s) to run this command.")
    else:
        raise error
```

in your error handler, always raise error