# Discord bot kick command error message python

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

So I found this code for a kick command and I would like to know how to make it so if the person who sent the kick command doesn't have permissions it replies to the user and says that they don't have the right permissions.

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, user : discord.Member,*,reason):
  await user.kick(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f'{user} kicked for {reason} by {ctx.author}')
```

That's the code

Comment: you can search online there's already people who've asked similar questions

Comment: @dogluva then perhaps you should find a similar question and flag this as a duplicate.

Comment: Another similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63369027/handling-errors-in-discord-py-no-permission#:~:text=You%20need%20to%20see%20if,ll%20be%20good%20to%20go.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling errors in discord.py (no permission)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63369027/handling-errors-in-discord-py-no-permission)

Answer (score 0):

This should send a message telling users that they don't have permissions if they try to use the command without the proper roles

```py
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions
#Import this at the top of your code
    
#Write the error handler below the code where you define the kick command
@kick.error
async def kick_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You don't have permission to kick members.")
```

For me I would write:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions
    
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=("prefix"))
    
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("Administrator")
async def kick(self, ctx, member : commands.MemberConverter, *, reason=None):
  await member.kick(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f"{member} has been kicked, reason: {reason}")
    
@kick.error
async def kick_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You don't have permission to kick members.")
```

Comment: Tell me if it works!

Comment: Thanks so much, it works great :) Have a great day or night