# Im trying to make a kick.error event within discord.py but im getting errors

Tags: python, discord.py

The Full Code Is Here

```py
@client.command()
@has_permissions(manage_roles=True, kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)

@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f"Sorry you don't have permission to use that command{message.author.mention}")
```

The Code That Is Giving Me The Errors is

```py
@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f"Sorry you don't have permission to use that command{message.author.mention}")
```

And My Error Message is this

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Normal\Downloads\DiscordServer Bot\PaddsIslandServer.py", line 76, in <module>
    @kick.error
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'error'
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000022572BA87C0>
```

I need some help as I dont know why Im getting these errors.
The 76Th Line is

```py
@kick.error
```

Comment: I incorrectly pasted but I fixed it.

Comment: I have no idea about this, but here's something similar to your code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70243074/16136190. I guess you need to add a `self` parameter so that it somehow passes it to the decorator.

Comment: Can you run `print(discord.__version__)`?

Comment: discord.__version__ : The term 'discord.__version__' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the      
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:7
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (discord.__version__:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @Pixler, I guess you need to run it in a Python file (`.py`), not CMD.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder I have version 1.7.3

Comment: @Pixler, I don't know why, but try [upgrading it to discord.py 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68638949/16136190). Have you tried comparing and fixing your code with the post I linked in my previous comment? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70243074/16136190)